# iTextSharp table cell colspan

Tags: c#, itext

I have a table and everything prints out ok, but there's just one problem.
Even though I set the columns right, it just prints out default widths for each column...

In this case, I tried setting a float[] (when instantiating the table) to see if I could set the widths for each column (even though the colspan of the Cell object should have already taken care of it), but even so it didn't change. Before, I have the integer for the number of columns, but the result was the same. I need some clarification about this, as part of the documentation is outdated.

```
doc.Add(NewTable(new float[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, new float[3] { 1, 5, 5 }, 250, 0, -1, 200, 150,
                                        new List<Cell>() {
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph("N.º do Auto:").SetFont(FontBold), ColorGray, new SolidBorder(1),1, 1, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE),
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph("fdgdfgdfg").SetFont(FontRegular), ColorGray, new SolidBorder(1),1, 2, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE),
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph("Data:").SetFont(FontBold), ColorGray, Border.NO_BORDER,1, 1, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE),
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).SetFont(FontRegular), ColorGray, Border.NO_BORDER,1, 2, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE),
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph("Morada:").SetFont(FontBold), ColorGray, Border.NO_BORDER,1, 1, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE),
                                            NewCell(new Paragraph("fdgdfgdfg").SetFont(FontRegular), ColorGray, Border.NO_BORDER,1, 2, 2.5f, HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                                        }));

/// <summary>
        /// Creates a new table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paddings">An array of values to set the table's paddings (top, right, bottom, left).</param>
        /// <param name="pointColumnWidths">An array of values to specify the number of columns ocupied by each cell in the row.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The table's width.</param>
        /// <param name="rowStart">The table row from which to start writing.</param>
        /// <param name="rowEnd">The table row to which to end writing (-1 for all rows).</param>
        /// <param name="horizontalPosition">The table's horizontal position (from the bottom left).</param>
        /// <param name="verticalPosition">The table's vertical position (from the bottom left).</param>
        /// <param name="cells">A list of cells to be added to the table.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Table NewTable(float[] paddings, float[] pointColumnWidths, float width, int rowStart, int rowEnd, float horizontalPosition, float verticalPosition, List<Cell> cells)
        {
            Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);

            table.SetPaddings(paddings[0], paddings[1], paddings[2], paddings[3]);

            foreach (Cell cell in cells)
                table.AddCell(cell);

            table.SetFixedPosition(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, width);

            return table;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new cell
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paragraph">A Paragraph object with the content.</param>
        /// <param name="backgroundColor">The background color of the cell.</param>
        /// <param name="border">The border to be applied to the cell.</param>
        /// <param name="rowSpan">The number of rows that the cell will ocupy in the table.</param>
        /// <param name="colSpan">The number of columns that the cell will ocupy in the table.</param>
        /// <param name="padding">The padding of the cell.</param>
        /// <param name="horizontalAlignment">The enum value for the horizontal alignment. Ex: HorizontalAlignment.LEFT</param>
        /// <param name="verticalAlignment">The enum value for the vertical alignment. Ex: VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Cell NewCell(Paragraph paragraph, Color backgroundColor, Border border, int rowSpan, int colSpan, float padding, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell(rowSpan, colSpan);
            cell.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
            cell.SetHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
            cell.SetVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);
            cell.SetPadding(padding);
            cell.SetBorder(border);
            cell.Add(paragraph);

            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `float[] pointColumnWidths` but is it not used anywhere.

Try this :

```
private static Table NewTable(float[] paddings, float[] pointColumnWidths, float width, int rowStart, int rowEnd, float horizontalPosition, float verticalPosition, List<Cell> cells)
{
    Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);

    table.SetPaddings(paddings[0], paddings[1], paddings[2], paddings[3]);

    foreach (Cell cell in cells)
        table.AddCell(cell);

    table.SetFixedPosition(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition, width);

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with the percentages. From their examples I thought it worked like the colspan from bootstrap, in which you have 12 columns total. There is no SetTotalWidth method anymore. I'm using version 7.1.2. It was my mistake, though. I had the float[] pointColumnWidths in the Table constructor. As I was experimenting to see what was wrong, I forgot to correct that.

Comment: So, I've corrected it in my main post. Modify in your too so I can accept your answer. I thanks again. ;)

Comment: @taiko, thank you for guidance, code has been change

Comment: You're welcome. And btw, I just realized that the float[] is not about the percentage. It's about the table width. For instance, if you have a table with 300 width the sum of the float values in the array will have to total the table (or one of the cells is going to be really big lol). In your example, you'd have 100 points filled and another 200 empty points, which one of the cells of have to fill.

Comment: The table api in itext has changed considerably from early 7.0.x to the current 7.1.x. This may even cause methods where arguments were percentages before now to interpret them as absolute widths.